# How to format html strings in c#?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I would like to create html helpers in ASP.net. What is the simplest way to create Html string/templates. I would like to create html blocks in this way:

```
<div class="simple">
   <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

So, I don't want to rewrite all quotes from double to single quotes like this:

```
 <div class='simple'></div>
```

It is not comfortable in bigger html codes. So is there any opportunity/syntax to C# handles it like HTML.

For example, in ES6 you can use this:

```
`<div class="simple"></div>`
```

Therefore it will be great if it is possible in C#.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question because I cannot understand what you need. Do you want to convert double quotes of attributes to single quotes?

Comment: If you copy/paste a HTML code you can rewrite from double quotes to single quotes. In Javascript, you don't have to do this. only put the html in this quotes: ` `. So what is best in c# to copy/paste html?

Comment: Why don't you do a find and replace all? Or do you want to do it programmatically?

Comment: Do it programmmatically. I only look for the best way for this.

Comment: `html.Replace('"', ''')`?

Answer (score 2):

The key thing is to escape the quote so it becomes valid within the string.

You can then use a simple [string format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx), [string builder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx), [tag builder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder(v=vs.111).aspx) or a nubmer of other approaches depending how complex your html code block is to build up the string.

```
using System;
namespace MvcApplication.Helpers
{
    public class TagHelper
    {
        public static string DivWithChild(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, className, string text)
        {
            return string.Format("<div class=\"{0}\"><span>{1}</span></div>",className,text);
        }
    }
}
```

Remember that any helper methods not declared on the page will have to have the namespace added to the web config do so you can use them.

```
 <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <namespaces>
        <!- add here.....  -->
        <add namespace="MvcApplication.Helpers.TagHelper"/>

      </namespaces>        
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `"` in a literal string can be written as `\"`.

E.g.

```
string s = "<div class=\"simple\"></div>";
```

Produces

```
<div class="simple"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use verbatim `@` to start the string and escape `"` with double `""` as follows.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string html = @"
                <div class=""simple"">
                    < span > Text </ span >
                </ div > 
            ";

            Console.WriteLine(html);

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

C# doesn't support HTML/ XML literals, but VB.NET does. If you manipulate HTML snippets a lot, you could consider creating helpers for it in a VB.NET module/assembly and calling them from your C# code. See [XML literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx).

Comment: Uhm, I think c# handles html/xml even better than vb.net.
You can use the `System.Web.HttpUtility` class to decode or encode or use much more functions.